# Need this type of sine wave animation without the cuts as like it is a wire. How to make?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

[Link for the video[image: ][1]]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tTYkHJjxdJkd1SB3rI5Rcoxq1GttfyQU

this is the link for the video that i have already made but it have cuts

---

[image: Thanks for your help]

The answer you posted was similar to the required animation by me.
But The spline is in square shape, I need a circular one. Can u help me with that.

and also how can we decrease the speed or increase the length of the spline.

Comment: What cuts? Do you want a continuous spline?

Comment: yes, i need a continous spline.

Comment: Use the [*Spline From Points*](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/spline/spline_from_points.html) node.

Comment: ok, then can i use the above method to animate it?

Comment: Yes, extract the locations of your matrices and use them as the input vectors of the node. Just like the example in the documentation.

Comment: How to extract the locations of the matrices, i don't know where start as I am fairly new to this animation nodes. Any help would really be appreciable.

Comment: I added an answer, not sure if this is what you are after, let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve you are trying to create can be described by the following parametric equation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p\\
\alpha p \sin({\beta t + p})
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are arbitrary constants, $t$ is the time, and $p$ is the parameter. We can implement this in Animation Nodes as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: ya the animation was similar as required by me, but the spline is in square shape, how to make it circle.

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh Increase the value of the Bevel Resolution in the Curve Object Output node to get a circular shape. Change the values of $\beta$, $\alpha$, and the end value of the range node, see what they will produce.

Comment: okay I got the circular shape, one last thing how can I get variable speed, like faster for 2 seconds then slower.

Comment: and how to make the wire straight before it changes to wave like form

Comment: and How to make the end of the spline same as like starting point, so that waves are formed between 2 points.

Comment: for example you can see the starting of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnray3HKjS8

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh First, since you are new here, welcome to StackExchange! Second, I know that you are just starting out and need help, and we love to help, however this isn't a support forum, please invest time and effort before you ask questions like this. Can you try to do those things you mentioned yourself?

Comment: Ok sure I will try it, thanks for helping.

Comment: Just 1 help please where are the values of alpha, beta in nodes

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh The values you are after are those of the multiply and divide nodes. Also the Stop value of the range node.

Comment: Hey, I know that I am disturbing you again and again, but I did tried all the values but neither of them made the spline to wavy form from centre, it still waving from the end point, I can only see changing the length and speed of the animation. Please Sir, help me with this, I really want to learn this.

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh Just make $\alpha$ variable, that is, a function that increases then decreases. Can you think of any function that does this?

Comment: umm....may be Divide function ?

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh Feel free to ask a separate question about this and I will answer it.

Comment: Was my answer wrong ?

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh Yes. Why do you think division would generate an increasting-decreasing function?

Comment: Are you asking for a mathematical function? Or some other function

Comment: @BrahmdeepSingh Look, just ask another question. Sorry if I was harsh.

Comment: How about Euler wiggle?

Comment: No, u r not harsh, m just dumb, and I won't mind ur comments because m here to learn.